# Is it possible to measure analog signals using cheap logic analyser?

Tags: logic-analyzer

I am using cheap logic analyzer with 8 channels, 1 CLK channel and GND. I am also using Logic2 software by Saleae and would like to know if it is possible to capture analog signals, like Sin wave? I intend to measure aux output signals on my STM32F4 Disco board. Here is the logic analyzer:
[image]

Comment: No, it is not possible.

Comment: Yes you can, it's easy: use an ADC chip and put the logic analyzer probes on the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That logic analyzer only can read digital inputs. Salae has 'logic analyzers' that have analog inputs but they are about 100x as expensive as that one.

You could try to read an ADC with the logic inputs, but generally ADCs do not autonomously output continuously valid data, so there might be control signals that would have to be created externally to the ADC and logic analyzer.

Answer (score 3):

You could but it isn't worth the effort (usually).
You would have to make an external comparator and resistor network to create the different voltage trip levels and write custom software to read the device and then interpret the different inputs into a single value.
See here for one example of this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_ADC
At that point you might as well buy the correct piece of equipment.

@bobflux's comment sounds even easier